# Apache POI - Support for pivot table slicer

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table, slicers

I want to create a slicer for a pivot table using apache POI library.Is there a way to do that?

I have done some research on this and found nothing related to this.

Comment: There is not any support for this in `apache poi`. And implementing this would be really expensive. We would need two additional `POIXMLDocumentPart`s (for Slicer and SlicerCache) and the `XSSFDrawing` would must support `mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`. And there are much complex relations between Sheet, Slicer, Dawing, SlicerCache and PivotTable. Possible?->Yes. Answerable in a queation here?->No. Implemented in `apache poi` sometime?->Maybe. Soon?->No.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter.So Is there a way to add a slicer to a pivot table in java.Will Aspose Library do?

Comment: "Will Aspose Library do?": I don't know. Maybe you ask there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache POI does not have the support for filter upto now.
However I have managed to create a slicer for an excell pivot table using Aspose Cells Library.

[Sample Code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aspose-cells/87c05ec07dd1a65ac6fcdf2fa896b01e/raw/5ee64d3ec512370df0b62277420a3d392616a749/Slicers-CreateSlicerToPivotTable.java)