# Apache Poi Excel Slicers Support Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, slicers

Does anyone know/use apache poi to create slicer in excel files? Does apache poi have support for slicers?

Any other Java api's available that can create slicers in excel file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache POI - Support for pivot table slicer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622954/apache-poi-support-for-pivot-table-slicer)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does not support Slicers: [mailing-list](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@poi.apache.org/msg12640.html). But
[GcExcel](https://www.grapecity.com/documents-api-excel-java/docs/online/overview.html) has support for Slicers: [Slicer docs](https://www.grapecity.com/documents-api-excel-java/docs/online/AddSlicerInTable.html)